# How to use IDocumentEvent, IDOMEvent and IEventTarget in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, mfc, internet-explorer-11, mshtml

I have a MFC application (CDialog) controlling an IE11 window (page loaded).

HTML Source:

```html
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function upperCase(x)
{
 var y=document.getElementById(x).value
 document.getElementById(x).value=y.toUpperCase()
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onchange="upperCase(this.id)">

</body>
</html>
```

In IE8 I can run 'OnChange' event with createEventObject and fireevent. But the same code can't be used on IE11.

I know for IE11 an event is created with [IDocumentEvent::createEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj192236(v=vs.85).aspx) and fired with [IEventTarget::dispatchEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh773207(v=vs.85).aspx).

But how to use them? C++ sample code not found in MSDN.

IDE: Visual Studio 2015 Community.